# Meaning of "nip"

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs

*Nip* is defined differently in two different dictionaries. From [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/nip), *nip* is defined as “to give somebody or something a quick painful bite or pinch”, whereas in [MWLD](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/nip), it is defined as “to bite or pinch (someone or something) lightly.”

Which is correct, or can they both be applied?

Comment: Both can be applied. Keep in mind you are citing learner's dictionaries. I think the OALD entry is trying to provide some additional nuance as to how the word is used in some contexts.

Comment: Here are [some examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22nip+at%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22nipped+at%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X&ei=44N4UOSADYyvygHegYHIDQ&ved=0CCEQpwUoAQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=c7ca4d29ee8c5836&bpcl=35277026&biw=1280&bih=939). It's used an awful lot in romance novels - something about that mix of pleasure and pain. Some material may be NSFW.

Comment: I think this is Not a Real Question/General Reference. The fact that one quoted definition happens to include the word *painful* and the other doesn't is hardly grounds for supposing they're meaningfully "different". OP could easily have looked at a few more online definitions to establish that when *nip* is used in any context relating to biting, it's always *a **small/trivial** bite*.

Comment: And here's an [NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=loving+nip%2Cgentle+nip%2Cplayful+nip%2Cpainful+nip%2Csharp+nip%2Cvicious+nip&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=20) suggesting the sense is shifting, though I could only do it with the noun.

Comment: @tchrist: I can't think of any "bite-related" contexts where *to nip* can imply a large, powerful, or serious bite. And I don't see how defining other, non-bite-related, senses addresses OP's "question". btw - I did actually mean *small **and/or** trivial*, as you seem to have recognised. Perhaps I should also have included ***and/or** quick*. My point being that there's nothing significant about *a **painful** nip* as opposed to ***just** a nip*. Relatively speaking, a nip is no big deal.

Comment: @StoneyB: You get a broadly similar picture from NGram if you replace **nip** with **slap**, so maybe it's not so much telling us that the meaning of *nip* is shifting. Perhaps we're just more likely to refer to, for example, a *playful nip/slap* today because the sexual connotations (and link between sex/violence) are more openly acknowledged.

Comment: In my mind, small cats and dogs may nip you, and the phrase "There is a nip in the air" does not evoke gales... So being nipped is not something I would consider very painful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two definitions you’ve given both apply, and in fact are really the same word with two slightly different senses.  They would both be listed as variants of the same basic word.

Understand that being so short, *nip* is a very old and very common word that has historically been put to a multitude of unrelated uses in English. The OED lists at least nine different words ***nip***, plus offers it as an archaic spelling for *neap*, too, plus comes in the *gnip* and *knip* variants itself. (Another sense of *nip* is in *catnip*.)

For the particular verb *nip* in question here, the OED offers these distinct senses, amongst many others:

> - *trans*.  To compress or catch between two surfaces or points; to pinch, squeeze sharply, bite.
> - To sever, remove, or take *off*, by pinching.
> - To defeat narrowly (in a sporting contest). U.S.
> - To check the growth or development of (something), after the manner of pinching off the buds or shoots of a plant. Also with *off*.
> - Of cold: To affect (persons, etc.) painfully or injuriously.
> - To touch or concern (one) closely; to affect painfully, to vex.
> - To snatch, catch, seize or take smartly. Also with *away, out, up.*
> - *slang.* To arrest.
> - *intr.* To give a nip or pinch; to cause or produce pinching.
> - *slang*. To move rapidly or nimbly.

A “love nip” is a light touch.  It may be related to the use of the noun *nip* in the game of Cricket:

> - A slight touch or stroke given to the ball by the batsman; a tip.

Or to this other noun use:

> - A small portion, such as may be pinched off something; a fragment, little bit.